# how to search within UL LI tree view with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I render a tree using UL LI.  Parents are not selectable but children are selectable by clicking on the checkbox. by default the tree view is not expanded. i am trying to add a search feature so that users can type a search criteria which is case in-senstive and tree would expand and show the matching by highlighting the results.

I have a JS function but it does seem to return matching neither it high lights results. any suggestions would be appreciated.

**HTML**

```
  <div id="errorCodes">

    <ul class="treeview">
        <li class="collapsable">
            <div class="hitarea collapsable-hitarea"></div>

            Pipettor Aspiration Dispense

            <ul class="treeview" style="display: block;">
                <li>
                    <input id="error150011" type="checkbox" value="150011"></input>

                    Unknown Error

                </li>
                <li class="expandable"></li>
```

**JS Function**

```
$("#search_tree").click(function () {

    $("#errorCodes li").removeclass("collapsible").find("input").removeClass("highlighted");
    //Search again
    $("#errorCodes li input:Contains(" + $('#plugins4_q').val() + ")")
  .addClass("highlighted").parents("li").addClass("collapsible");

});
```

Comment: I can see a typo - li class ="collapsable" but in your JS you wrote collapsible

Comment: Is it supposed to be searching the `input` values or the `li` text? A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to search the text adjacent to the inputs (rather than the `input` values) I've wrapped each `input` in a `label` and had the script search that. There's a lot of guess-work gone into this solution but the following may be of use:

```
$("#search_tree").click(function () {
    //close and unhighlight everything
        $(".opened, .highlighted").removeClass("opened highlighted");
    //Perform search
        var term = $('#plugins4_q').val().toLowerCase();
        //for case-insensitive searches we need to use a filter:
            $('#errorCodes li label').filter(function(){
                return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1;
            })
        //highlight matches
            .addClass("highlighted")
        //open all ancestors
            .parents("li").addClass("opened");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s4Qkz/

Comment: Worked for me. Only chaned $("#search_tree").click(function () { to $("#search_tree").onkeydown(function () {